# Why won't the Google Maps API add markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using the following code to try and add a map to a `div` and place a marker at the user's current location. It's the first time I've tried anything like this and I've been playing around with it for the last few days, following different tutorials and the stuff on Google's website, but I just cant get it to work. The map will appear, but no matter what I try the marker(s) won't show up. I've tried adding static markers too, using co-ordinates, and nothing will show up on the map. It's starting to drive me a little mad. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.36652, -2.29855),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map =
        new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.36652,-2.29855);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });
}

marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: you have used google maps V2(GBrowserIsCompatible,GMap2) and in remaining places google maps V3. change to one version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made the switch to V3 and changed the first part of the code but I'm still having the same issue, the map will show but the markers wont appear.

Comment: If you have changed the code, edit your question so the quoted code reflects the true situation. Your question may be closed if there is not enough information to help solve it.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the first post with the current code that I have. I went back and followed the google docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers) but its continuing to do the same thing - showing the map only with no markers.

Answer (score 1):

Your line
`marker.setMap(map);`
is outside the function. You should have received a message indicating that `marker` was undefined.

Move that line into the function — above the last `}`.

Note that using `var map...` inside the function limits the scope of `map` to that function: the variable will not exist once that function has completed. If you want to do other things with the map, you will need to declare
`var map;`
in global scope (outside any function) and then use that variable inside the function with
`map = ...` (no `var`).

Comment: in fact the marker.setMap(map); line shouldn't even be required, as Kai is specifying the map attribute in the marker options